# How do I test my DAO update method in an AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests test?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, transactions

I'm using Java 8, JUnit 4.12, Spring 4, and Hibernate 5.2.12.Final.  I want to test a Hibernate method where I update some rows.  The method looks like this

```
        final CriteriaBuilder qb = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaUpdate<FailedEvent> q = qb.createCriteriaUpdate(FailedEvent.class);
        final Root<FailedEvent> root = q.from(FailedEvent.class);
        q.where(qb.and( qb.equal(root.get(FailedEvent_.objectId), objectId) ));
        q.set(root.get(FailedEvent_.flaggedForDelete), true);
        affectedRows = m_entityManager.createQuery(q).executeUpdate();
     return affectedRows > 0;
```

I have the following JUnit test to verify this

```
public class FailedEventDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
...

    @Test
    public final void testFlagForDeleteByObjectId()
    {
            final String eventId = "testId";
            final FailedEvent event = failedEventDao.findByEventId(eventId);
            Assert.assertFalse("A pre-condition fo this test is that an failed_event record with id \"" + eventId + "\" have a non-empty object id.", StringUtils.isEmpty(event.getObjectId()));
            Assert.assertTrue(failedEventDao.flagForDeleteByObjectId(event.getObjectId()));
            final FailedEvent foundEvent = failedEventDao.findByEventId(eventId);
            Assert.assertTrue("Failed to mark flag for deletion.", foundEvent.getFlaggedForDelete());
    }   // testFlagForDeleteByObjectId
```

But my test fails on the last line,

```
Assert.assertTrue("Failed to mark flag for deletion.", foundEvent.getFlaggedForDelete());
```

Is this because the transaction hasn't completed yet so nothing has been updated in the database?  What's the way I can validate that the right records are updated?

Comment: It should be the same transaction. You can set SQL statements logging in Hibernate to check what SQL is actually being executed

Comment: I turned that on and verified the SQL statements are executed.  Indeed, the "affectedRows = m_entityManager.createQuery ..." line is indicating multiple rows affected so I though tthat meant stuff was executed successfully.

Comment: I don't mean to throw spanner in your question, but may I ask, why are you unit testing database operations? I am not sure what value you are getting out of unit testing your database operations. From your asserts it doesn't look like you are testing any business requirements. Most of the time we just mock all the stuff that requires live running systems for unit tests. Quite frankly, If you are doing this just to satisfy your code coverage requirements then you are wasting your time. Your time will be better spend writing tests where it adds more value.

Comment: What returned value for method `foundEvent.getFlaggedForDelete()`?

Comment: Could you send `FailedEvent` class plus the `flagForDeleteByObjectId` and `findByEventId` methods?

Comment: @user7294900 - At what point in my test do you want me to check the value of the "foundEvent.getFlaggedForDelete()" method?

Comment: @Dave is method returning `boolean`?

Comment: @user7294900, oh yes, right.  It is returning the Boolean object (as opposed to the primitive).

Comment: Please remember to mark the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try @AfterTransaction Annotation to test the result.

```
    @AfterTransaction
    public final void theRealTest()
    {
            Assert.assertTrue("Failed to mark flag for deletion.", foundEvent.getFlaggedForDelete());
    }
```

https://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-transactional-junit4-test-code-example.html

if this is also not working try:

> "So, you need to create multiple transactions inside your test method.
>   As you can see, you cannot use
>   AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests, because it creates a
>   single transaction for the whole test method, and cannot use bare
>   AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests, because it creates no transactions
>   at all.
>
> The solution is to use AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests and manage
>   transactions inside your test method programmatically.
>
> You need to inject PlatformTransactionManager into your test, create
>   TransactionTemplate from it and use it to demarcate your transactions
>   as described in 11.6 Programmatic transaction management."

found here: 
[Using AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests with commit halfway through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979757/using-abstracttransactionaljunit4springcontexttests-with-commit-halfway-through)

Comment: Where am I adding this code -- to my JUnit test class?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at the link I added. Just a an other method under your actual @Test annotated method.

Comment: https://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-transactional-junit4-test-code-example.html

Comment: One other thing -- in my test, "foundEvent" is local to that method, but as you've put it in a separate method, you want me to make this a global variable?  Also does this @AfterTransaction run after every test I have in that class (I only listed one test, but it has several)?  If so, is tehre any way just to get the test itself to work without affecting all the other tests?

Comment: You should consider not to extend the abstract class and use a different approach. For example @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

@Transactional

Annotation on the class. Check this out https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/write-transactional-unit-tests-spring/#section_7

Comment: Check my second answer

Comment: Please do not forget to mark my answers as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider not to extend the abstract class and use a different approach. 
For example

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@Transactional
```

on the class.

Like:

```
  package com.example;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.model.Person;
import com.example.service.PersonService;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/spring-beans.xml")
public class PersonServiceIntegrationTests {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Test
    public void shouldCreateNewPerson() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("Kenan");
        person.setLastName("Sevindik");

        long countBeforeInsert = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from t_person", Long.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(2, countBeforeInsert);

        personService.create(person);

        long countAfterInsert = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from t_person", Long.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(3, countAfterInsert);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDeleteNewPerson() {
        long countBeforeDelete = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from t_person", Long.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(2, countBeforeDelete);

        personService.delete(1L);

        long countAfterDelete = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from t_person", Long.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, countAfterDelete);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFindPersonsById() {
        Person person = personService.findById(1L);

        Assert.assertNotNull(person);
        Assert.assertEquals("John", person.getFirstName());
        Assert.assertEquals("Doe", person.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Check this out https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/write-transactional-unit-tests-spring/#section_7

Or

```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

@ContextConfiguration(

  classes = { StudentJpaConfig.class }, 

  loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)

@Transactional

public class InMemoryDBTest {

     

    @Resource

    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

     

    @Test

    public void givenStudent_whenSave_thenGetOk() {

        Student student = new Student(1, "john");

        studentRepository.save(student);

         

        Student student2 = studentRepository.findOne(1);

        assertEquals("john", student2.getName());

    }

}
```

Check this out 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-test-in-memory-database